# io is not defined -- HTML/Javascript-Meteor app

Tags: javascript, html, sockets, meteor, socket.io

I am trying to develop a chat component having my server side code in Meteor. To establish a socket connection I want to expose io object which we get from npm library socket.io-client.

I am adding a script tag to my HTML page which looks as shown below

```
<script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Then I am trying to connect to server side socket as shown below

```
var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
```

This is where I get "io is not defined" error

Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: If there is way to establish a socket connection between meteor server and plain html/js client, please share the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.3/socket.io.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Comment: But can we rely on pointing to external lib ?? It would always be helpful if we have the file within our code right ? Which is why I am not using that

Comment: First check if you get error or not then use the relative path to the file on your server for socket.io

Comment: Relative path to the server would be something like
http://localhost:3000/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js
which gives the same error as io not defined

Comment: And when I try with cdnjs library, io would be defined but its CORS issue.

Comment: just remove the localhost:3000 and use the relative path to the file. 
Also why are you getting CORS in that CDN? you should not get that

Comment: If I remove localhost:3000 and give the file path in the browser address bar it is showing me the file content, which is as expected I guess.
Regarding cors issues, it might be because I am trying to run the html file by opening directly in the browser which leads in have a prefix "file:///" in the url. I can solve the cors issue

Answer (score 0):

> am adding a script tag to my HTML page which looks as shown below

Use the wrapper package instead:

https://atmospherejs.com/joncursi/socket-io-client

> io would be defined but its CORS issue

Follow the instructions in https://enable-cors.org/server_meteor.html